# Report errors in the real terminal and restart itself to login interface

Tags: boot

My machine abruptly report errors  and immediately return to the Login Interface.
(the errors are printed in the real terminal with cursor blinking too quick to capture a snapshot).

I re-log-in and check the syslog

```
$ head /var/log/syslog
May 13 05:22:54 alpha syslogd (GNU inetutils 1.9.4): restart
May 13 05:22:57 alpha vmunix: [22389.180680] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
May 13 05:22:57 alpha vmunix: [22389.193601] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
May 13 05:22:57 alpha dhclient[28475]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x607b5c72)
May 13 05:22:58 alpha dhclient[28475]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.31.117 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x725c7b60)
```

It prompt that `GNU inetutils` restart

```
$ last reboot | head -3
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-18-generi Sun May 12 08:12   still running
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-18-generi Sat May 11 19:35 - 00:00  (04:24)
reboot   system boot  4.18.0-18-generi Sat May 11 10:24 - 00:00  (13:35)
```

It shows that the machine did not reboot since yesterday

```
$ last | head -3 | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
me   :0           :0               Mon May 13 06:05   still logged in
me   :0           :0               Sun May 12 09:18 - 06:05  (20:46)
me   :0           :0               Sun May 12 09:09 - 09:18  (00:08)
```

but re-login at 06:15

The most recent x-session-error message before re-login

```
$ journalctl _UID=1000 --since '2019-05-13 07:30:00' --until '2019-05-13 08:12:00'  -r | cat
-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-03-17 07:29:49 CST, end at Mon 2019-05-13 17:18:51 CST. --
May 13 07:50:33 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8400]: (EE) client bug: timer event16 tap: offset negative (-286ms)
May 13 07:49:39 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8400]: (EE) client bug: timer event16 tap: offset negative (-35ms)
May 13 07:49:38 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8400]: (EE) client bug: timer event16 tap: offset negative (-31ms)
May 13 07:49:38 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[8400]: (EE) client bug: timer event16 tap: offset negative (-275ms)
May 13 07:48:23 alpha org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[8844]: # watch_established: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0)
May 13 07:48:23 alpha org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[8844]: # unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (active: 0, establishing: 1)
May 13 07:48:23 alpha org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[8844]: # watch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
May 13 07:48:22 alpha systemd[8325]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
May 13 07:48:22 alpha systemd[8325]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
May 13 07:48:22 alpha systemd[8325]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
May 13 07:48:22 alpha systemd[8325]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Found left-over process 13165 (code) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
May 13 07:48:22 alpha systemd[8325]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
May 13 07:48:22 alpha systemd[8325]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Found left-over process 13157 (code) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
May 13 07:48:22 alpha systemd[8325]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
```

The detailed information about the machine:

[image]

The problem occurred two or three times daily which does interrupt the work routine.

I tried months but failed to take a picture when it report errors in a real terminal.

How could I fix the problem?
or retrieve the errors from log?

The  non-empty files `/var/crash`

```
$ ls -lS /var/crash
total 180376
-rw-r----- 1 gaowei   whoopsie 98063988 May  7 09:45 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 root     whoopsie 75786893 May 13 07:30 _usr_bin_emacs-gtk.0.crash
-rw-r----- 1 gaowei   whoopsie 10463542 May 12 08:25 _usr_share_code_code.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 gaowei   whoopsie   268660 May 11 15:35 _usr_bin_fcitx-dbus-watcher.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 gaowei   whoopsie   104470 May 13 07:24 _usr_bin_sogou-qimpanel.1000.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     whoopsie        0 May 13 07:29 _usr_bin_emacs-gtk.0.upload
```

The most recent is `_usr_share_code_code.1000.crash` on 08:25 yesterday which uploaded as:

[Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BfkfW8P94S/)

Comment: Are there crash files for those times in /var/crash? If so, post one crash file at http://paste.ubuntu.com and link to it in your question.

Comment: thank you, I pasted it to paste.ubuntu.com @user535733

Comment: No, that's binary gibberish. The crash file is text. Open the file in a text editor. Copy and paste 100% of the text into paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: too huge to paste to paste.ubuntu. I send it to firefox send @user535733

Comment: @Alice Your link has expired. Post to https://paste.ubuntu.com/ instead and provide that link. Thanks.

Comment: ty for the kind help. @WinEunuuchs2Unix append the paste link to the question.